# Read timed out when using Hystrix on RPC

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign

I use @HystrixCommand to package a RPC，if not use Hystrix it will run normally。This RPC is not a microservice instead a normall http

```
 @Override
@HystrixCommand(commandProperties = {@HystrixProperty( name ="execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds",value="5000")},fallbackMethod="doAccountQueryFallback")
public CBIBAcctQueryResponseVO doAccountQuery(@RequestBody CBIBAcctQueryRequestVO cbibAcctQueryRequestVO) {
        //initialize message
        // ....
    try {
        responseMessage = (AcctTypeInqResponse) HTTPUtil.sendHttp("http://********", inqRequest, *****.class);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        //...
    }
    logger.debug("success");//  1
    return cbibAcctQueryResponseVO;
}

public CBIBAcctQueryResponseVO doAccountQueryFallback(@RequestBody CBIBAcctQueryRequestVO cbibAcctQueryRequestVO){
    //....
}
```

**the error infomation like:**

```
feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing POST http://****/doAccountQuery

at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:67)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:104)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.doAccountQuery(Unknown Source)
...
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
```

I change the value of the @HystrixCommand properties. Though I set a long time it will also show this exception,do // 1 and do not call fallback method.

When I set 100 ，it show this exception,do // 1 and  call fallback method.
I suspect is it send some times?

When I set 1 ，it does not show this exception  and  call fallback method.
it's actually expected.

**the doAccountQuery is a mircoservice and there is a normal http request in the doAccountQuery. I want to package this normal  http request with Hystrix only(not use feign).but once i add @ @HystrixCommand on the doAccountQuery.the microservice doAccountQuery itself will timed out,but it also will return the result (retransmission？ only the first transmission timed out ?  I dont know)**

1 also try

```
ribbon:
ReadTimeout: 60000
ConnectTimeout: 60000
```

but useless

Besides sometimes the exception will become
 **connect timed out** and  not do //1  and even not call fallback method!

I want have some debug suggest thanks!

Comment: your exception shows feign usage but I don't see that in your example. spring-cloud's feign configuration uses Hystrix if available. It may be you have multiple hystrix commands.